# Battery backup schematic

Tags: battery-charging

I want to create a simple battery backup for my circuit.

[image: Battery Charging circuit]
This circuit is for battery charging

[image: Battery switch circuit]

This is circuit battery switching, when power fails the switch-over would happen. 
Am I on the right path of implementation.

Regards,

Chaitannya

Comment: You should use a different charger. Some chargers handle this automatically. It will be much easier and more reliable and use fewer components.

Comment: Can you suggest any components ?

Comment: Look for TI parts that have "power path."